# Dynamic accessing of javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Hi I have an array of dom elements (li) as shown below:

```
Array[4]
0:li.ui-steps-item.ui-state-default
1:li.ui-steps-item.ui-state-highlight
2:li.ui-steps-item.ui-state-default.ui-state-disabled
3:li.ui-steps-item.ui-state-default.ui-state-disabled
```

I have a click event, and am appending a class to the list. Means when I click if the li is not the activated li, then other li's class will be appended with this extra class.

```
private _btnClick(_btn: any, config:any):void {
    var nodesArray=Array.prototype.slice.call(this._vcr.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('li.ui-steps-item'));
    for (let x in nodesArray) {
        if (nodesArray[x] != nodesArray[this._activeIndex]) {
            nodesArray[x].classList.add('ui-state-disabled');
            console.log(nodesArray[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now what I need to achieve is, I need to add a new class to the items(lis) before the active li and i need to add another class to the lis after the active li. Or Only add the class `ui-state-disabled` to the li after the active li. How can I do that? Any idea guys?

Click button code:

```
private _btnClick(_btn: any, config:any):void {
        this.buttonEvent.emit({btn:_btn, formBtns:this._formBtn}); // Event emitter

        let arrLen: any = config.length-1;

        if (_btn.BtnType=="next"){
            if (this._activeIndex < config.length -1) {
                this._activeIndex++;
            }
            if (this._activeIndex == arrLen){
                _btn.label = "Confirm";
                // _btn.disabled = true;
                // _btn.class = 'btn-success';
            }
            for (let x in this._formBtn){
                if (this._formBtn[x].BtnType  == "previous"){
                    this._formBtn[x].disabled = false;
                    this._formBtn[x].hidden = false;
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        else if (_btn.BtnType=="previous"){
            this._activeIndex--;
            for (let x in this._formBtn){
                if (this._formBtn[x].BtnType  == "previous"){
                    if(this._activeIndex == 0) {
                        this._formBtn[x].hidden = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                if(this._formBtn[x].BtnType == "next") {
                    if(this._formBtn[x].label == "Confirm") {
                          this._formBtn[x].label = "Next";
                          this._formBtn[x].disabled = false;
                          this._formBtn[x].class = 'btn-text';
                          continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        this._emitStepVal(this._finalConfig);
        // console.log(this._vcr.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('li.ui-steps-item'));
        var nodesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(this._vcr.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('li.ui-steps-item'));

        var addClass = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < nodesArray.length; i++) {
            if (addClass) nodesArray[i].classList.add('ui-state-disabled');
            if (i === this._activeIndex) {
                addClass = true;
            }       
        }

    }
```

Comment: may check the index and after that index add the value in.. Is there any function in javascript to append values after checking a specific index in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to append a class to the `li` occurring after the active `li` you can do:

```js
var addClass = false;

for (var i = 0; i < nodesArray.length; i++) {

  if (addClass ) 
     nodesArray[i].classList.add('ui-state-disabled');
  else
     nodesArray[i].classList.remove('ui-state-disabled');

  if (i === this._activeIndex) addClass = true; 
}
...
```

Within the comments you said that the "previous" button logic was not working correctly. My suggestion is to do something like:

```js
...
else if (_btn.BtnType == "previous") {
  if (this._activeIndex > 0) {
    this._activeIndex--;
  }
  if (this._activeIndex == 0) {
    _btn.disabled = true;
    //_btn.hidden = true; // if you want to hide the previous button when at the first item
  }
  for (let x in this._formBtn) {
    if (this._formBtn[x].BtnType == "next") {
      this._formBtn[x].disabled = false;
      this._formBtn[x].hidden = false;
      break;
    }
  }
}
...
```

Comment: but under the else condition, the items before activeIndex also will be added right?

Comment: Yes, see the alternative I just posted, to only add a class to the `li` following it

Comment: sorry, just fixed a bug in the code. The `classList.add` needs to come before `addClass = true`, or it will apply it to the active `li` as well

Comment: You may also like to put in a `classList.remove('ui-state-disabled');` before the add, so that when you click on another `li` to make it active it will first remove any `ui-state-disabled` that occur before it in the array

Comment: Sacrelett, can u add that in my code and update in the answer. I dun really get it sorry

Comment: I have updated my question with my button click function. But I can only go one way now. It works perfect, but when go backward by clicking back button the first element near the active one is not getting the class for some reason.

Comment: do i need any different implementation for the previous button type clicks?

Comment: The logic in the `previous` is different to the `next` button. Have it follow similar logic to the `next` button

Comment: basically if next, the activeIndex ++ and if previous then activeIndex--

Comment: Thats the main diff between these 2 buttons

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138778/discussion-between-k-scandrett-and-blackdaemon).